# microsoft graph api: patch nested structure

Tags: graph, microsoft-graph-api

To update a 'simple' field item in sharepoint we can patch using the graph api:
[https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/items/{item-id}/fields](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/%7Bsite-id%7D/lists/%7Blist-id%7D/items/%7Bitem-id%7D/fields)
using

{
"td_documentLookupId":"22"
}

But how to perform an update if the required structure is a nested json`enter code here:

```
{         
   "td_documentLookupId":"22",
   "td_object":{
                "LookupId":7,
                "LookupValue":"title"
                }
}
```

This returns an invalid request. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: May I know how did you create these properties?

Comment: They were configured in sharepoint. The api lets me query them:   "fields":{
      "@odata.etag":"\"xxx"",
      "FileLeafRef":"8000-W8-PRO-PID-DO-0001 6.0.pdf",
      "Title":"Straat 1",
      "td_documentLookupId":"22",
      "td_object":[
         {
            "LookupId":7,
            "LookupValue":"Nabezinktanks"
         },
         {
            "LookupId":8,
            "LookupValue":"Retourslibsysteem"
         }
      ],

Comment: Try something like this `{         
   "td_documentLookupId":"22",
   "td_object":[{
                "LookupId":7,
                "LookupValue":"title"
                }]
}`

Comment: Let me know if that works.

Comment: This returns: "invalid request" as well

Comment: Give a try making 7 as string "7" as the lookup ids are always strings. Copy this payload as it is. `{"td_documentLookupId":"22","td_object":[{"LookupId":"7","LookupValue":"title"}] }`

Comment: This also returns a invalid request error

Answer (score 0):

I found the following to work for the above case, using PATCH protocol:

```
{         
    "td_documentLookupId":"22",
    "td_objectLookupId@odata.type": 'Collection(Edm.Int32)',
    "td_objectLookupId": [7]                        
}
```

`td_objectLookupId` is a multiselect list. As per above it can patch a list of values e.g. [7,8,9]

The name of the to-be-patched column is a combination of the column name with the nested column name (td_object + LookupId)